# Что лучше использовать в моем случае fragment или только layout

Tags: java, android

В общем приложенные(табло) будет 9 видов спорта,с одинаковым интерфейсом(button, textview, chronometer), как лучше , использовать каждую кнопку как фрагмент, или писать отдельно в каждом layout

[image: Приложение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты созданы для динамических интерфейсов. Если у вас одни элементы не заменяют другие - толку от фрагментов будет мало. Если видимый экран единственный в приложении - можно вообще не заморачиваться с какой-либо структурой, у вас в одном файле вся логика и 100 строк может не занять

Comment: Дело в том что таких экранов как на скрине должно быть 9 штук, они будут отличаться но незначительно (где-то будут добавляться кнопки , где-то убираться)

Comment: тогда у вас 2 варианта. Первый: сделать на одном экране весь функционал, который может понадобится, и в зависимости от выбранного вида спорта часть скрывать. Тут можно попробовать поиграться со фрагментами, но скорее с целью ознакомится с ними, чем сделать более читабельный и "правильный" код. Второй - сделать под каждый вид спорта отдельный экран. Можно вынести часть логики в отдельные объекты, например, счет одной команды - это одна большая вьюшка, два экземпляра такой вьюшки добавляем на каждый экран. И тогда как реализовать это, 9 вьюшек или 9 активити - не так уж важно.

Comment: спасибо огромное